# Autofac cannot resolve parameter 'System.String applicationClientId' of constructor

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, autofac

I have the following class/interface structure:

```
class ProviderSetting
{
    public delegate ProviderSetting Factory(string applicationClientId,
        string appKey);

    public ProviderSetting (string applicationClientId, string appKey)
    { ... }
}
```

and

```
class Provider : IProvider
{
    public Provider(ProviderSetting setting)
    { ... }
}
```

and

```
class Ingestor: IIngestor
{
    public Ingestor (IProvider provider)
    { ... }
}
```

I use autofac to perform dependency injection in the following manner:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<ProviderSetting>().AsSelf();
builder.RegisterGeneratedFactory(typeof(ProviderSetting.Factory));
builder.RegisterType<Provider>().As<IProvider>();
builder.RegisterType<Ingestor>().As<IIngestor>();
```

and resolve as follows:

```
var settings = container.Resolve<ProviderSetting.Factory>().Invoke("<appId>", "<appKey>");
var provider = container.Resolve<IProvider>(new TypedParameter(typeof(ProviderSetting), settings));
var ingestor = container.Resolve<IIngestor>(new TypedParameter(typeof(Provider), provider));
```

But I get the exception that:

> DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'ProviderSettings' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
>       Cannot resolve parameter 'System.String applicationClientId' of constructor 'Void .ctor(System.String, System.String)'.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It's trying to inject a `ProviderSetting` even though you're creating your own in the resolve stage. Have you tried adding a parameterless constructor to `ProviderSetting`, or resolving that separately?

Comment: I wanted to avoid adding parameterless constructor because the parameters are required by the ProviderSetting class and instantiating it without parameters would break the ingestor.

Answer (score 5):

The error occurs here:

```
var ingestor = container.Resolve<IIngestor>();
```

That's because autofac tries to resolve the `Provider` for `Ingestor` but for `Provider` it tries to resolve `ParameterSettings` which can't. The reason for this is that you haven't registered any parameters for `ParameterSettings`. The code:

```
var provider = container.Resolve<IProvider>(new NamedParameter("setting", new ProviderSetting ("<appId>", "<appKey>")));
```

Only resolves an instance of `IProvider` and does not register the above parameters.

To register those parameters you need to use `WithParameters` extension:

```
builder.RegisterType<ProviderSetting>()
    .AsSelf()
    .WithParameters(
    new[] 
    {
        new NamedParameter("applicationClientId", "someClientId"),
        new NamedParameter("appKey", "someAppKey")
    });
```

Then you can resolve services without explicitly providing those parameters:

```
var provider = container.Resolve<IProvider>();
var ingestor = container.Resolve<IIngestor>();
```

**UPDATE**:
If you want to provide those arguments while resolving you could create factory delegate for this:

```
public delegate ProviderSetting ProviderSettingFactory(string applicationClientId, string appKey);
```

And register it:

```
containerBuilder.RegisterGeneratedFactory(typeof(ProviderSettingFactory));
```

Then you can resolve it like this:

```
var factory = container.Resolve<ProviderSettingFactory>();
ProviderSetting setting = factory("someClientId", "someAppKey");
```

In the end you can always do it like that:

```
var provider = container.Resolve<IProvider>(new NamedParameter("setting", new ProviderSetting ("<appId>", "<appKey>")));
var ingestor = container.Resolve<IIngestor>(new NamedParameter("provider", provider));
```

Comment: I can't do this during registration of ProviderSettings because I want to resolve the Provider and Ingestor multiple times with different provider settings, but with single registration

Comment: @DhruvJoshi in which class would you like to provide those arguments? In Provider?

Comment: no, when I resolve the Provider and Ingestor, I want to resolve them 3 times, with 3 different ProviderSettings to each Provider and Ingestor instance being resolved

Comment: @DhruvJoshi Those 3 provider are 3 different classes or the same?

Comment: They are the same providers.
Also with the update you posted, I get the same exception as before

Comment: @DhruvJoshi in which line?

Comment: var ingestor = container.Resolve<IIngestor>(new NamedParameter("provider", provider));

Comment: @DhruvJoshi Tested it and it works for code in question

Comment: @DhruvJoshi It is just all of the code from your question with the last block of code replaced with `var provider = container.Resolve<IProvider>(new NamedParameter("setting", new ProviderSetting ("<appId>", "<appKey>")));
var ingestor = container.Resolve<IIngestor>(new NamedParameter("provider", provider));`

Comment: I'm trying to use the delegate method and have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @DhruvJoshi If you use TypedParameter you should use `typeof(IProvider)` instead of `typeof(Provider)` because in constructor there is `IProvider`